# Set varying row heights depending on row data in slickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

I need to set a different row height for a few items in my grid but it seems to break the layout when I do.  Is there a way to do this with slickGrid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is variable rowheight a possibility in SlickGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805094/is-variable-rowheight-a-possibility-in-slickgrid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SlickGrid's row height be dynamically altered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535164/can-slickgrids-row-height-be-dynamically-altered)

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid doesn't support variable height rows.

Comment: true. but i have addressed this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29399927/262256) with some custom codes =)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a library similar to SlickGrid, but with variable row height support you may want to consider giving DobyGrid a try: https://github.com/globexdesigns/doby-grid