# Javascript data grid with auto adjusting row height

Tags: datagrid, javascript

I would like a JavaScript UI library that can create a Data Grid that fully supports variable row height. I.e. each row can have a different row height that automatically adapts to fit the content, and lets the text wrap to the next line.

I have seen people looking for this feature in many free libraries(e.g. [SlickGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805094/is-variable-rowheight-a-possibility-in-slickgrid)), but it took me quite a while to find some viable alternatives. I would prefer ones that are free for commercial use, but I would also consider paid products.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this in some detail, and found the following results:

Of all the alternatives, I have only found one that is free for commercial use - [dojox DataGrid][1], however it is not clear how you could use custom editors with this (most commercial ones offer this).

There are quite a few viable alternatives that require payment for commercial use: dhtmlxGrid, jQuery EasyUI DataGrid, jQWidgets, Wijmo Grid widget, JideTable, and Sencha ExtJS Grids.

Of these, I would personally say the best is dhtmlxGrid http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/ - Free version is GPL, Pro version is $199.

More detailed notes are below:

- dhtmlxGrid supports wrapping, rich text, many data sources, event handlers, custom editors. Looks like it has solid documentation and support forums.
  Free version has "Ability to create custom cell editors", "Inline cells editing", etc. Comparison with pro.
  Free version does not have "Multi-line footers", "Colspans and rowspans", some serialisation options (XML). Does not appear to be a problem.
  Over 100 samples.
  Free version is GPL (use with care!). Pro version is $199.
  They also have a separate Rich Text Editor. Free. dhtmlxeditor. The docs show more buttons.
  Discussion of using dhtmlxGrid with dhtmlxeditor. Should be possible. They had some trouble, but last version might work.
  Integration with dhtmlxDataStore might be useful.
  Providing Undo/Redo Operations might be useful. Requires pro version.
  Built-in Cell Editors: Search for "Usage of Cell Editors (eXcell)" in here (samples here) and "Define new Cell Editors (eXcell)" here.
  I would say this is the best solution. Though a little doubt on Editors.
- dojox DataGrid looks ok. Not as good as dhtmlxGrid. Supports wrapping, rich text, some data sources, some event handlers. But unclear on custom editors.
- Sencha ExtJS Grids. Requires a Commercial License. Price is $3,225 for up to 5 developers.
- jQuery EasyUI DataGrid looks okish, but a bit simple. Supports
  autoRowHeight, rich text, json import (but no others?), event
  handlers.
  Free version is GPL (be careful!) -  Pro version is
  $449. 
  Probably a good solution, though a little doubt on Editors and export.
- jQWidgets has auto row height, but is not free for commercial
  use ($199).
- Wijmo Grid widget (wijgrid) has auto row height, but
  costs $495.
- JideTable has auto row height, but costs $99. Doesn't
  look as solid as others.

It is worth noting that GPL may be ok if your only users are staff that have to log in to access it - apparently GPL only requires you to give source to people who use it (but you should confirm this yourself).

Comment: wrt `Slickgrid`, i have addressed this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29399927/262256) where i provide a customisation that works using the existing `Slickgrid` API