# Wrapping Text inside the TableColumn (Python/Bokeh: HTMLTemplateFormatter)

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a DataTable with two TableColumns that looks like the one below:

| date | top20_vals |
| --- | --- |
| Sept-2020 | (John, 35), (George, 65), (Chris, 98), (Tim, 5), (Jack, 32)... |
| Oct-2020 | (Rachel, 39), (Greg, 25), (Duke, 83), (Bobby, 17), (Daniel, 8)... |
| Nov-2020 | (Andrea, 42), (Tim, 15), (Doug, 19), (Fred, 57), (Robby, 32)... |
| Dec-2020 | (Dom, 55), (Paul, 68), (Brian, 3), (Louis, 65), (Evelyn, 31)... |

As you can see, the top20_vals TableColumn has run-on text which I would like to wrap, but have been unsuccessful so far. Below is my code so far; I don't know the appropriate syntax for the HTMLTemplateFormatter. Is there anyone who is more familiar with Python/Bokeh syntax that can help me out please?

```
template = """
             <style>
              div{word-wrap: normal;}
              </style>
              <div><%= value %></div>
           """

formatter = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template = template)
table_columns = [TableColumn(field = 'date', title = 'Date'), TableColumn(field = 'top20_vals', title = 'Top20 Names', formatter = formatter),]
t1 = DataTable(source = source, columns = table_columns, width = 600, height = 800)
show(vform(t1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh uses [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) for rendering of data tables in HTML. Some evidence for this is the css style names attached to the cells at runtime:

> slickgrid_318648 .slick-cell {
> height: 25px; }

The height is assigned in the styles for the rows and the cells (not inherited), so a cell's content can't readily change the layout of the table (e.g. produce a taller row).

This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544586/slickgrid-auto-word-wrap-and-adjust-the-height-of-rows) suggests that the row height is a fundamental part of the layout of Slickgrid and cannot be easily altered.