# How can i add image with text in "slickgrid" cell?

Tags: slickgrid

I am trying to implement "text and image in same cell by using slick grid". I have not found any answer for my requirement. Can anyone answer my question...?

Answer (score 3):

Cell customizations are generally handled via [formatters](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters.html).

Beware that the `row height` can be set via [grid options](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options), but [will be static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931903/set-varying-row-heights-depending-on-row-data-in-slickgrid?lq=1), so if the images are to vary in size you'll need some heavy render customizations or perhaps a different grid framework.

```js
 
var grid;
var data = [{id: 1, src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj07W.jpg?s=128&g=1', txt: 'Some text' }, {id: 2, src: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4a7ca5a83afc1e7a43bf518ccaa3c9be?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1', txt: 'Some different text' }];
var columns = [
    {id: "id", name: "rowId", field: "id"},
    {id: "img", name: "Image", field: "src", formatter: function(args){  return "<span>"+data[args].txt+"</span><br/><img src ='" + data[args].src + "'></img>" }}
];

var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    forceFitColumns: true,
    rowHeight: 175    
};

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

<script src='http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js'></script>
<script src='http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.core.js'></script>
<script src='http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js'></script>
<script src='http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.formatters.js'></script>
 
<div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I found one example http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-plugin-headerbuttons.html In this example when my mouse pointing over the 2nd column header , it is showing "help image"... In the same way... my requirement is, I need same behavior in 2nd column cells .. is it possible....?

Comment: You should update/edit the original question with this additional information as it is a completely different context from my interpretation of the question asked. You should be able to accomplish anything in a "body" cell that is seen in a header cell, but with much more implementation required on your part since the header cell functionality is already implemented and provided via a plugin.