# Is it possible to set row height auto in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

Is it possible to set slickgrid row height depending upon the content size.
   If any possibilities to wrap text in a particular cell and the corresponding row to the slickgrid.

Thanks,
Rajendhiran M

Comment: [Is variable rowHeight possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805094/is-variable-rowheight-a-possibility-in-slickgrid) may be of interest. You can render the contents of the cell any way you desire with a custom formatter, the content sensitive/dynamic sizing will be the task to overcome.

Comment: @Rajendhiran: did you able to achieve it?